# GTM Cookies consent - current state in custom HTML as variable?

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager, cookieconsent

I have cookie consent in GTM and every built-in tag work well (Analytics, etc). I know that I can make condition for "Custom HTML" via "**Require additional consent for tag to fire**" but I need add custom HTML as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xyzSymbol = {{Symbol of order}};
var xyzPrice = {{Total price of order}};
var hasAdStorageConsent = ?????  // true or false if has user "ad_storage"
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.xyz.cz/rs/static/rc.js"></script>
```

Does exists a variable with current ad_storage state? Or has a callback for it? or something etc.

Thank you for any help.